# How to refactor this snippet into a one liner?

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary, conditional-statements

I have a array of objects, and my goal is I'm trying to filter out repeats. I am using a dictionary and using it as my "filter". I am trying to come up with different ways to refactor this, but haven't come up with anyway. I know there has to be a way. Can anyone figure it out? It being a dictionary is pretty tough.

```
filterFunc(object: any): void {
  const filter = {};
  object.forEach(obj => {
    if (!filter[obj.id]) {
      filter[obj.id] = true;
    }
  }
}
```

I understand there is a `Array.prototype.filter` method, but I am trying to filter out values in a object. So I wasn't able to come up with anything simple in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method

```
filterFunc(list: Array<any>): void {
 return list.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (!acc[curr.id]) {
        acc[curr.id] = true;
      }
      return acc;
    }, {});
}
```